# How to use logger level status in the code in Python

Tags: python

I have the following logger (Python 2.7):

```
logger = logging.getLogger('solution')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = ....
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)
```

The logger can be set to Debug / Info etc...

Later on my code I do get requests from APIs.
I can connect to test API or Production API.

```
#test
#url = 'http://...test....com/connect/'
#production
url = 'http://.......com/connect/'
```

Is there a way that I can use the logger level so that the script would know by itself if it should choose the test url or the production url? As you can see correctly one of them is in comment and I have to change it manualy every time.

Something like:

```
If logger.level = 'DEBUG':
    url = 'http://...test....com/connect/
else
   url = 'http://.......com/connect/'
```

I know I can set a global variable to solve this but I'm wondering if the logger can be used for that.

Comment: you can but you shouldn't, for sanity's sake. Did you try that code you posted?

Comment: @ManuValdés The script is working. Sometimes it fails due to many reasons and then I need to debug and trace the issue. The thing is that the script connects to more than 8 different APIs (actually it's 16 because each API has also post AUTH ) ... If there is a mix of production / test then nothing will work.

Comment: You should do this the other way around - set logger level and URL *both* based on some third value, e.g. an environment variable.

Comment: Expanding on jonrsharpe's response, think about what is the single source of truth in your program -- would you want to trust logger level as the authority on whether it is running in production mode or test mode?

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can i convert `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to used with global variable? `var='DEBUG' string = 'logging.{}'.format(var) logger.setLevel(string)`?

Comment: If the value is going to be a log level name you could use `getattr`, but it might be clearer to have e.g. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG if dev_mode else logging.INFO)`.

Comment: @UltraInstinct Well.. I'm just asking what is the best approach for this issue. I just had an Idea... I could be wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe dev_mode is just a Boolean variable which I set?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd pass it either via the environment or as an argument when starting the app.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's a single script.. I'll just set it at the beginning.

Comment: You should accept the answer that actually answers the question as posted! It's not their fault it's an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use logging.getLogger('solution').getEffectiveLevel() to get the level in integer format:

10 for Debug
30 for Default and so on..

You can then use these values to activate control statements. Basically these values are what stored as constants in "logging.DEBUG". So constant "logging.DEBUG" is actually 10.